# Trim substrings of a filename, each matching a pattern to a given length

Tags: text-processing, sed

In the example that follows, the pattern is separated by `-` and the length is 3. My question is: Is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
$ echo $foo
./abcd-123-efghij-45678.pdf
$ echo "$foo" | sed -E 's:([^-\.\/]{3})([^-]*):\1:g'| sed "s/$/.${foo##*.}/"
./abc-123-efg-456.pdf
$ foo=${foo%.pdf}.djvu
$ echo $foo
./abcd-123-efghij-45678.djvu
$ echo "$foo" | sed -E 's:([^-\.\/]{3})([^-]*):\1:g'| sed "s/$/.${foo##*.}/"
./abc-123-efg-456.djvu
```

What I ultimately need this command for, is to replace `...` by it inside `for f in $(find . -name pattern); do mv $f $(...);done`

Comment: can you please explain bit more, I am having hard time to understand your question. what do you mean by "replace `...` by it inside" ?

Comment: I want to have the files that match a certain pattern have equal size. `for in ...; do mv $f $(echo $f | sed -E ...)` with the `sed` part as shown in the example.

Comment: What pattern I want to search and outcomes is already stated at the beginning of the question, followed by an example.  Here's another example of input: `gtr-tomwaits-callfromistanbul-chord-ehaugen.mp4
gtr-tomwaits-callfromistanbul-mribot.mp4` and the desired output for length=6 `gtr-tomwai-callfr-chord-ehauge.mp4
gtr-tomwai-callfr-mribot.mp4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could shorten that to

```
echo ./abcd-123-efghij-45678.pdf | sed -E 's:([^-\.\/]{3})([^-]*):\1:g; s/$/.djvu/'
```

but otherwise, it's pretty much the best you can do with `sed`.

Comment: OK, and is there a better way with a command other than sed?

Comment: You could do it in shell alone, but that would be more complicated. You could do it in awk or perl, or some other language that has a split operation. That might be easier to understand. But in general, `sed` is a good tool for that kind of job.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this would help you, For example you want to search all `*.txt` files

```
for f in $(find . -type f -name "*.txt"); 
 do 
    echo mv "$f" $(echo "$f" | sed -E 's:([^-\.\/]{3})([^-]*):\1:g;s/$/.'"${f##*.}"'/')
done
```

If you are satisfied with the result then remove `echo` and run the code again.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple `perl` script.  I doubt very much if it's more "efficient" in terms of CPU usage or memory consumption than `sed` but you'd be extremely unlikely to notice any difference in run-time and it's easier to read, modify, and use:

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# default to substring lengths of 3
my $maxlen=3;
if ($ARGV[0] =~ m/^\d+$/) {  # if first arg contains only digits
  $maxlen = shift;
};

while(<>) {
  chomp;
  s/#.*|^\s*|\s*$//g;  # strip '#' comments, leading & trailng spaces
  next if (m/^$/);     # skip blank lines

  my ($path,$ext) = '';
  my $filename = $_;

  # extract path (if any)
  if (m/^(.*\/)(.*)/o) {
    ($path,$filename) = ($1,$2)
  };

  # extract filename extension (if any)
  if ($filename =~ m/(^.*)(\..*)$/) {
    ($filename,$ext) = ($1,$2);
  };

  # split into fields on '-', reduce each field to $maxlen.
  my @fields=split /-/,$filename;
  @fields = map { substr($_,0,$maxlen-1) } @fields;

  print "$path" . join('-',@fields) . $ext . "\n";
}
```

Save the script with a descriptive filename, and make it executable with `chmod +x scriptname`.  I just used your U&L name.

Input:

```
==> erwann1.txt <==
abcd-123-efghij-45678.pdf
./abcd-123-efghij-45678.djvu

==> erwann2.txt <==
gtr-tomwaits-callfromistanbul-chord-ehaugen.mp4 
gtr-tomwaits-callfromistanbul-mribot.mp4
```

Output:

```
$ ./erwann.pl 3 erwann1.txt 
abc-123-efg-456.pdf
./abc-123-efg-456.djvu

$ ./erwann.pl 6 erwann2.txt 
gtr-tomwai-callfr-chord-ehauge.mp4 
gtr-tomwai-callfr-mribot.mp4
```

You could run it as:

```
ls -1 *.mp4 | ./erwann.pl 6
find . -type f -name '*.pdf' | ./erwann.pl
```

The script will handle filenames with any characters except newlines in them.  If there's any chance that filenames will have newlines in them, the script is easily modified to support NUL-terminated input records (maybe use `Getopt::Std` or `Getopt::Long` to handle command-line options)